# How many 14/2 w/g romex wires can i put in a 1” pvc conduit?

Tags: electrical

I want to run 14/2 w/g romex wires from my 150 amp fuse box in the garage to my proposed game room in the basement. To make the wires look neat and clean for the Installation, I am going to use 1” pvc electrical conduit to protect and give a neat appearance to the wires in the garage. How many wires can I put through the 1” pvc conduit?

Comment: I do not know, but romex really reduces the amount of circuits in a conduit compared to single wires(THHN?).

Comment: Is this conduit acting as an open-topped sleeve, and how long is it?